# C# Small Tray Application starting as windows Server

Tags: c#, windows, forms, service

I have created a windows Form tray application in C# .NET 4.0 that does some random things, not important, for Windows XP SP3.

The intention is that the application is to be started using Windows Services and should be running as `LocalSystem` with "Allow service to interact with desktop" checked. I understand the security implications and that services are not meant to be running GUI's etc, but this is the point of the program and is being used for training purposes.

When I start the application using the `Services.msc` utility it starts fine, but after about 10 seconds it states "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

I have looked at a number of other solutions without any luck, for example:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dac443c1-f2fc-49c6-bdd4-5426edc946ee/how-to-start-calcexe-from-windows-service-

I don't really care about a nice programming example. I can either create a service then have the tray application called API's, but I don't know if the tray application will run with elevated privs, or create a forms application and hack it to run as a Windows XP service or get a proper service to launch an exe being my tray application...

Any examples would be much appreciated or links to coding examples etc.

Answer (score 1):

For a windows service, if your overridden OnStart method performs a lot of work, you will get the "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" error.

You can call the ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime method with enough time required to perform whatever work is needed.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for refrence.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this happens to someone else. I just used the Windows 2003 Resource kit and used 'SRVANY'.

More information is available here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

and here:
http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=197

I just followed the instructions except for ticking the checkbox in Services "Allow Service to Interact with Desktop"

Thanks for the Answer Dietz, it is probably the correct way in getting it working but this is just a simple hack.